# NPM says peer dependency missing but packages are installed

Tags: npm, strapi

I am trying to install a Strapi project. After running npm install I get the following peer dependency warnings:

```
npm WARN eslint-config-airbnb@13.0.0 requires a peer of eslint@^3.9.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-config-airbnb@13.0.0 requires a peer of eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y@^2.2.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-config-airbnb@13.0.0 requires a peer of eslint-plugin-react@^6.6.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-config-airbnb-base@10.0.1 requires a peer of eslint@^3.9.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-ga@2.5.6 requires a peer of prop-types@^15.6.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-ga@2.5.6 requires a peer of react@^15.6.2 || ^16.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

However, when I check the installed version of these packages everything seems fine. For example:

```
$ npm view eslint version
5.9.0
$ npm view prop-types version
15.6.2
```

This is from the Strapi-generated package.json (dependencies for prop-types and react I added)

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^7.1.1",
    "eslint": "^4.19.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^13.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.11.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.7.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.5",
    "strapi": "3.0.0-alpha.15",
    "strapi-utils": "3.0.0-alpha.15",
    "strapi-hook-mongoose": "3.0.0-alpha.15",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "react": "^15.6.2"
  },
```

Does this have to do with locally vs globally installed packages? Any help super appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
npm WARN eslint-config-airbnb@13.0.0 requires a peer of eslint@^3.9.1
```

means that it requires a **3.9.x** version of **eslint**, so the **5.9.0** version you have installed is too high. I would recommend you update to version **17.1.0** of **eslint-config-airbnb** and then use **eslint 5.3.0** with it.

Comment: Oh wow, so even though the message reads "**none** is installed", it actually refers to it just not being the **right** version? I thought it meant that it found no version at all. Is the solution then to upgrade all the dependent packages to accept the higher version of the installed packages?